# Help me unserstand this XML key/value declaration from the WebDAV specs

Tags: xml, database, properties, webdav

See this example from [RFC2518](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html#rfc.section.8.1.1):

```
    <D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:">
      <D:response>
           <D:href>http://www.foo.bar/container/</D:href>
           <D:propstat>
                <D:prop xmlns:R="http://www.foo.bar/boxschema/">
                     <R:bigbox>
                          <R:BoxType>Box type A</R:BoxType>
                     </R:bigbox>
                     <R:author>
                          <R:Name>Hadrian</R:Name>
                     </R:author>
                     <D:creationdate>
                          1997-12-01T17:42:21-08:00
                     </D:creationdate>
```

WebDAV allows the getting/setting of in part predefined or arbitrary key/value pairs. Here one prop retrieved is from the "DAV:" namespace, "creationdate", abbreviated as "D". Another is from the "http://www.foo.bar/boxschema/" namespace, indicated by its shorthand "R".

I undersstand the first one, but what about the second?
As a JSON data structure this reads as

```
{
  "DAV:": {
     "creationdate": "1997-12-01T17:42:21-08:00"
  },
  "http://www.foo.bar/boxschema/": {
     "bigbox": {
        "BoyType" : "Box Type A"
     },
     "author": {
        "Name" : "Hadrian"
     }
  }
}
```

As I understand WebDAV, resources should be able to set/get *key-value-pairs*, but the RFC here presents a nested multi-level data structure! How should I flat these out to key-value pairs?
Or do I get the nesting in the XML wrong, is there something that I need to throw away/skip? That would explain it...

```
$key{'DAV:creationdate'} = "1997-12-01T17:42:21-08:00";
$key{'http://www.foo.bar/boxschema/.bigbox.BoxType'} = "Box Type A";
```

or what?? How do you guys handle these? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be looking at [RFC 4918](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html), not RFC 2518.

To answer your question: WebDAV properties essentially are XML fragments, which can be simple (plain text), or more complex. See [Section 4.3](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#property_values) for details.

And yes, this is hard to represent in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the quick hint!

From a glance at RFC4918 and your answer, I begin to realize (accepting it will take another few hours) that the WebDAV properties are in no way an extension of what has become known as filesystem xattr(ibs), so I won't be able to fully/(easily) implement WebDAV's property demands via my filesystem's extended attributes API.

Tell me if I am wrong (please do!) aargh...

Comment: You can always force this type of property content into strings, after all, that's what you have in PROPFIND and PROPPATCH. Of course it's non-trivial if you want these properties to be exposed to non-WebDAV clients. I think the easiest approach is to simply reject mixed content, although this will make the implementation non-conforming. Depends a bit on your requirements.

Comment: Diverging a bit from the RFC is also what I had in mind - at least for now. Still, I think WebDAV went a little far there, with requiring PROPPATCH to support simple key-value pairs *and* more complex structures.. If they had saved the more complex part for a Class n spec and kept simpler key-value for Class 1 servers, I think more people would use this feature. -- Probably that's why so many implementations lack PROPPATCH support...

Comment: Just for the record: any hint on how to more or less reliably parse out those varied simple and mixed content requests into a predictable structure? - At the moment I can't see how I may teach my script to look for all the possible locations of namespaces, how to tell the parser about depth limits, etc. (I am working under Perl)

Comment: You're using an XML parser, right? It should provide you with all the information you need...